# After MVC3 publish, just update the views

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, view

.NET/MVC3 newbie, so please bear with me!

I've searched for this answer all over but cant find exactly what im looking for, so here it comes...

Lets say that i'm developing an MVC3 app with Visual Web Developer Express and i go about deploying the site using the built in publishing tool.

But now that my site is up and running i find that i need to make a minor adjustment in one of the views. I update the view and save the file, and use my FTP program to upload the new file.
The problem is that MVC3/.NET doesn't seem to refresh/change the view, because it's still using the old version.

Of course I have tried refreshing (in many different browsers even), but it still won't load the new view.

Is this normal behaviour, meaning that i have to publish every time i make some minor adjustments (kinda time consuming)? I really can't imagine that this is the case, so i'm wondering if you could shed some light over this?

Appreciate any replies!

/Mikael

Comment: Are you using compiled views?  If not, recycle the appPool (if you have access to IIS on the server ) or try and force a rebuild on the server by adding an extra space to the web.config.  If you are, copy the new bin up to the server.

Comment: I do not have access to any IIS settings, that i'm aware of. It is a normal online hosting company. Do you mean that by changing the web.config, i'm forcing the server to "rebuild"?

Comment: Not really a 'rebuild' but it will JIT which should send out the latest views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upload the view (.cshtml) file and that is the *ONLY* part of the application that has changed, a refresh will reflect the change - you may have to ctrl+f5 to clear the temp cache.  However! If you change *ANY* of the controller code or action code, or any c# (or vb if thats what you use), then you *MUST* re-upload the compiled .dll associated with the entire application in order for the changes to be reflected.

Comment: When you write "or any c#", does this even include the c#/razor code in the views. Im aware that i have to re-compile my controllers etc, but are the views fair game? And how about the web.config or the global.asax?

Comment: For web.config you can manually upload that if changed.  What I meant in any c# code was mostly if you are changing any file that ends with .cs, like a model, a controller, a data access layer, global.asax.cs, etc.  I actually had not considered if you changed c# code in the view, which may also require a rebuilding of the project (but I do not think it does).