# how to make changes on a deployed Asp.net MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, web-deployment

Is it possible to make changes on a deployed MVc application
i have attach the worker process to my application hosted on local IIS, i am able to debug my application perfectly, but how to make changes on a deployed application or i have to publish again for changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views you can change on the fly - the actual method depending whether they are precompiled or not - but any changes in the .cs files or the dlls require you to publish again. There are several answers to similar (duplicate?) questions:

[asp-net-mvc-update-pre-compiled-razor-view-file-live-in-production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352905/asp-net-mvc-update-pre-compiled-razor-view-file-live-in-production)

[after-mvc3-publish-just-update-the-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056995/after-mvc3-publish-just-update-the-views)

Comment: I change my action controller or any .cs file.  That case what should I do. Thanks in advance