# ASP.NET MVC website viewmodel not updating after publish, but works fine running in release

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, publish

I made some updates to my ASP.NET MVC website, including a change to this ViewModel. It works 100% fine running IIS Express in Visual Studio after a build in Release. However, after publishing... it is not updating this specific ViewModel for whatever reason.

[image]

That property is 100% there. I have no doubt this should be working. Something is going on with either the publish or the IIS server itself. I think it is the publish, because I have been deploying the last build .zip file and it works fine. Only the recent publishes with this new update are acting up. It's driving me crazy.

Is there anything I can do to make sure this is publishing fresh or building fresh?

EDIT: I was able to manually copy my project's .dll file to my web server and it worked. Why would the publish not update my .dll file? I am publishing to a fresh .zip file each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you change only the views, CSS, javascript, you could `xcopy` command to only the modified files but if you change the source code you need to recompile the application and redeploy it.if you change your source code you only need to xcopy your particular dll. No need to redeploy whole application unless you didn't split your application in multiple logical layers.

You can refer the below link for more detail:

[how to make changes on a deployed Asp.net MVC website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696385/how-to-make-changes-on-a-deployed-asp-net-mvc-website)